# Is that possible to change the color of directory text using workbench.colorCustomizations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the colour of my directory on Vs Code Terminal using workbench.colorCustomizations. If anyone knows how to change it, could you help me?
Below is my screenshot with an arrow showing which text I want to change.

Screenshot here

[file:///Users/llancruzz/Desktop/Screenshot%202023-03-07%20at%2020.44.58.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83pys.png)

I've tried all commands of workbench.colorCustomizations by Vs Code.

Comment: what do you mean? Is it not set to your `terminal.ansiBlue`?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `colorCustomizations`.  It is a shell profile setting.  Search for `zsh prompt color`.